# Forcing an asynchronous parallel loop to stop immediately- C#

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

Here is my method for requesting information from Azures FaceAPI.

I finally realized that in order to make my application work best, a bunch of my security camera frames must be grabbed in parallel, then sent away to the Neural Network to be analyzed.

(Note: it's an Alexa custom skill, so it times out around 8-10 seconds)

Because I grab a bunch of frames in parallel, and asynchronously, there is no way to know which of the images will return a decent face detection. However, when a good detection is found, and the request return Face Data, there is no way to stop the rest of the information from returning.

This happens because the Security camera images were sent in Parallel, they are gone, the info is coming back no matter what.

You'll see that I'm able to use "thread local variables" to capture information and send it back to the function scoped "imageAnalysis" variable  to serialize and allow Alexa to describe people in the security image. BUT, because the loop is in Parallel, it doesn't break right away.
It may only take a second or two, but I'm on a time limit thanks to Alexas strict time-out policies.

There doesn't seem to be a way to break the parallel loop immediately...

Or is there?

The more time is spent collecting the "imageAnalysis" Data, the longer Alexa has to wait for a response. She doesn't wait long, and it's important to try and send as many possible images for analysis as possible before Alexa times-out, and also keeping under the Azure FaceAPI limits.

```
        public static async Task<List<Person>> DetectPersonAsync()
    {
        ConfigurationDto config = Configuration.Configuration.GetSettings();

        string imageAnalysis;
        using (var cameraApi = new SecurityCameraApi())
        {
            byte[] imageData = cameraApi.GetImageAsByte(config.SecurityCameraUrl +
                                                        config.SecurityCameraStaticImage +
                                                        DateTime.Now);

            //Unable to get an image from the Security Camera
            if (!imageData.Any())
            {
                Logger.LogInfo(Logger.LogType.Info, "Unable to aquire image from Security Camera \n");

                return null;
            }

            Logger.LogInfo(Logger.LogType.Info, "Attempting Image Face Detection...\n");


            Func<string, bool> isEmptyOrErrorAnalysis = s => s.Equals("[]") || s.Contains("error");


            imageAnalysis = "[]";

            List<byte[]> savedImageList = cameraApi.GetListOfSavedImagesAsByte();

            if (savedImageList.Any())
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(savedImageList, new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                },
                    async (image, loopState) =>
                    {
                        string threadLocalImageAnalysis = "[]";
                        if (!loopState.IsStopped)
                            threadLocalImageAnalysis = await GetImageAnalysisAsync(image, config);

                        if (!isEmptyOrErrorAnalysis(threadLocalImageAnalysis))
                        {
                            imageAnalysis = threadLocalImageAnalysis;
                            loopState.Break();       
                        }
                    });
            }

            // Don't do to many image analysis - or Alexa will time-out.
            Func<List<byte[]>, int> detectionCount =
                savedImageListDetections => savedImageListDetections.Count > 5 ? 0 : 16;


            //Continue with detections of current Camera image frames
            if (isEmptyOrErrorAnalysis(imageAnalysis))
            {

                    Parallel.For(0, detectionCount(savedImageList), new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                    },
                        async (i, loopState) =>
                        {
                            imageData = cameraApi.GetImageAsByte(config.SecurityCameraUrl +
                                                                 config.SecurityCameraStaticImage +
                                                                 DateTime.Now);

                            string threadLocalImageAnalysis = "[]";
                            if (!loopState.IsStopped)
                                threadLocalImageAnalysis = await GetImageAnalysisAsync(imageData, config);

                            if (!isEmptyOrErrorAnalysis(threadLocalImageAnalysis))
                            {
                                imageAnalysis = threadLocalImageAnalysis;
                                loopState.Break();
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        try
        {
            //Cognitive sense has found elements(people) in the image
            return new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer().DeserializeFromString<List<Person>>(imageAnalysis);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //No elements(people) detected from the camera stream
            Logger.LogInfo(Logger.LogType.Info,
                string.Format(
                    "Microsoft Cognitive Sense Face Api Reports: \n{0} \nNo people in the CCTV Camera Image.\n",
                    ex.Message));

            return new List<Person>(); //Empty
        }
    }


    private static async Task<string> GetImageAnalysisAsync(byte[] image, ConfigurationDto config)
    {
        string json;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                config.MicrosoftCognitiveSenseApiKey);


            // Request parameters.
            const string queryString =
                "returnFaceId=true" +
                "&returnFaceLandmarks=false" +
                "&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender,accessories,hair";

            const string uri =
                "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + queryString;

            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(image))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                try
                {
                    Logger.LogInfo(Logger.LogType.Info, json);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Bear in mind that there's no concept of cancellation in HTTP. If you've *sent* stuff for analysis, trying to kill any *local* processing won't necessarily stop it from counting against you at the server end.

Comment: You cannot stop it. Once you make the request, it is out of your control. You can send them chunks at a time and if you dont have the desired response, send another junk.